Using TOP 1 in LEFT JOIN subquery not working
According to all the documentation I have read this should work on most sql databases. I am running SQLAnywhere and it's docs say this should work.
I am aware that I could run this as a normal subquery from within the SELECT section but I need to get multiple columns (I have cut this down for simplicity).
Adding 'TOP 1' to a subquery in a LEFT JOIN to get only the single row wont return any results for me. Running the subquery on it's own works perfectly. I have also tried using the LIMIT key word with the same nil results.
Any suggestions please?
SELECT candidate.*, timesheet_header_date_exported
FROM candidate
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 timesheet_header.candidate_id_pf, timesheet_header_date_exported
           FROM timesheet_header 
           ORDER BY timesheet_header_date_exported DESC) lexported ON (lexported.candidate_id_pf = candidate.candidate_id_pf)
ORDER BY candidate_code

CANDIDATE TABLE:
candidate_id_pf int
candidate_code int
candidate_surname Varchar(50)
candidate_address Varchar(200)
....
TIMESHEET_HEADER TABLE
timesheet_header_id_pf int
candidate_id_pf int
timesheet_header_no int
timesheet_header_date_paid date
timesheet_header_date_exported date

each candidate row has multiple timesheet_header rows.
I'm trying to get the oldest timesheet_header_exported date for each candidate.
If I use MAX in the subquery I get the correct result but I need to collect other columns in the same subquery and I dont wont multple rows.

You're getting no rows back at all from the main query, or you aren't getting matched rows on the LEFT JOIN?  Also, if you can create a repro case in a SQL Fiddle it would make helping easier.

Presumably timesheet_header contains records for lots of candidates but you are only bringing back a single record from this table - and that record is not going to match to all but one candidates. Is that what you are trying to achieve - as it seems like an odd query to be running?

Sorry for the confusion. Im getting all the candidate rows. It's the subquery - the oldest timesheet_header_date_exported I am trying to get back. Which works if I run it own it's own (with hardcoded candidate_id_pf).

And SQL Fiddle doesn't support sqlanywhere, which is where I believe the problem is.

Maybe if you updated your question with example data for the two tables, and the result you are trying to achieve, I’d would make more sense (to me)?

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

Since you only select one of the timesheet_header columns, you can replace the LEFT JOIN with a correlated subquery in the SELECT list:
SELECT candidate.*,
       (SELECT MAX(timesheet_header_date_exported)
        FROM timesheet_header lexported
        WHERE lexported.candidate_id_pf = candidate.candidate_id_pf)
FROM candidate
ORDER BY candidate_code

